# Tool to log changes to a mysql database

Tags: mysql

, I'm trying to achieve the following functionality on one of the applications I'm developing.
1) Both mobile app and browser users access the same database
2) Android users store some of that data locally

Now the tricky part is that data can change and if an android user(s) have previously stored this info locally, what is stored becomes garbage.

So now here comes the question. Is there a tool that can log changes made to a mysql database, possibly into a defined table?
So that if a change is made to data that an android user has, these changes can be made to the local repo as well whenever that user logs in. I've been looking about but I haven't found a simple solution to this so far.
I've seen a few posts on here about this, but I'm hoping something simpler has been developed lately.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just write it yourself. Sounds pretty minor.

Comment: Questions asking for recommending any tool, tutorial, or any other off-site resource are considered off-topic on SO.